# Visual Studio C# - Tier Separation

Tags: c#, n-tier-architecture

I'm learning about the different tiers in software development, such as the presentation tier, logic tier..etc.

So I have this RaceTrackSimulator project which is a Windows Forms Application. I want to separate all the classes (logic) from the GUI (presentation) and I did so like this:

[image: The Project Solution in Visual Studio]

But now the problem is, I don't know how to allow the classes to access and modify components of the GUI such as textboxes and labels. I think this is just a simple namespace issue, but that doesn't make sense because in each class it says:

```
namespace RaceTrackSimulator.BusinessLogic
```

How do I resolve such an issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you can't access the classes from the form, or cannot access the form from the classes?

Comment: If you simply copy the code for presentation logic into a separate file, but still have it modifying GUI components, you haven't separated the business logic from the presentation logic!

Answer (score 2):

You have just separated the business tier classes in separate folder which doesn't actually qualify as separate tier altogether. You should rather move all this classes in a separate project (example, class library project) and use the dll of that class library to your presentation tier form application.

You can as well choose, to write your business tier as WCF service and deploy them. In turn, your client/presentation layer will consume the service then to access business layer; which is one way good cause then for all different client's (UI or other) you don't have to ship the dll exclusively.

In your specific case, the problem could be that the namesspaces are different and in which case make sure, you are importing the correct namespace.

Answer (score 0):

A few things it could be without looking at the actual code. The namespaces would be different from the 3 classes compared to your Form as they are in a different folder.

Also ensure that the components visibilty level is set to "Public" in the properties tab on the Form Designer. Once they are public, you should be able to access them in any of the 3 classes that you have created.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put a

```
using RaceTrackSimulator.BusinessLogic;
```

At the top of the file where you are referencing your objects?

Answer (score 0):

Where your code resides in terms of namespacing is irrelevant. You've done that fine. All you need to do is supply a means of accessing the components from your business logic classes. There's a multitude of ways of doing that depending on your requirements. You could supply a post(Object state) method in your form, and instantiate your logic class passing a reference to the form object. Your business logic can then simply post anything it likes back to the form and it's up to the form how it then handles the UI logic based on the data/message it receives from the logic layer. Or you could make your components more publicly visible to the logic layer. Or you provide an interface that allows access to the components directly.

Also, what you are calling Business Logic in your example above is not really logic. It's business model classes, by the looks of it.